# Something happened to my sound during checkbox testing

Tags: sound, checkbox

I was running checkbox and I went through a sound portion, got bored and killed the test. Problem is that something has happened to my sound as a result. It sounds really scratchy like it's way too loud for the speakers. What has happened and how do I fix it? Any ideas? Perhaps there's something I can run that will re-initialize the sound? Note that a restart did not help, which is the most alarming.

...OK, that was weird. Changing the volume seems to have fixed it. Should I leave this here for others to find it?

Comment: Could you try running: `sudo alsa reload`

Comment: I think it busted my speaker, nothing makes my sound goes back to normal... the left speaker are making a crackling sound  every time I play anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the exact same thing happen to me running Ubuntu 16.04,found your posted question, and then that last thing about changing the volume clued me in.  Looks like Checkbox simply maxes out the computer volume as a part of its test.  Then you turn on your desktop speakers and they blare.  Turned it back down, no biggie.